# Uploading images in custom post form

Tags: posts, images, uploads

I have custom form for posting in my theme file. I also need to upload photos(videos also but photos are more important now) and I prepared form using wp handle upload function. It's working, images are uploading but they're not inserting into the post. Please help me. Here is a code full http://cdpst.net/s8i5jsfuf and here is the relevant bit:

```
if ( $_POST['question_post'] == '1') {
    $question_title = $_POST['question_title'];
    $question_content = $_POST['question_content'];
    $question_category = $_POST['cat'];
    $question_tags = $_POST['question_tags'];

    if ($_FILES) {
        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
            $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
            // $newupload returns the attachment id of the file that
            // was just uploaded. Do whatever you want with that now.
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Code is not reachable. Please post the relevant bits here.

Comment: http://codepaste.dev7studios.com/item/hww3rpe5s

Answer (score 2):

Let's presume your FILE variable is called 'files' and can contain multiple inputs (i.e. name="files[]")

1) First upload the files

```
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
  $upload_file_url = array();
  foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key => $value_data)
    {
        $errors_founds = '';

        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$key] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
            $errors_founds .= 'Error uploading the file!<br />';

        if (!array_key_exists($_FILES['files']['type'][$key], $mime))
            $errors_founds .= 'Invalid file type!<br />';

        if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$key] == 0)
            $errors_founds .= 'Image file it\'s empty!<br />';

        if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$key] > 524288)
            $errors_founds .= 'Image file to large, maximus size is 500Kb!<br />';

        if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key]))
             $errors_founds .= 'Error uploading the file on the server!<br />';

        if ($errors_founds == '')
            {
                //Sanitize the filename (See note below)
                $remove_these = array(' ','`','"','\'','\\','/');
                $newname = str_replace($remove_these,'', $_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
                //Make the filename unique
                $newname = time().'-'.$newname;
                //Save the uploaded the file to another location

                $upload_path = $uploads['path'] . "/$newname";
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key], $upload_path);
                $upload_files_url[$upload_path] = $uploads['url'] ."/$newname";
            }
    }
```

2) Process the successfully uploaded files

```
if (count($upload_files_url)  > 0)
    {
        foreach ($upload_files_url as $filename_path => $upload_file_url)
            {
                $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename_path), null );
            $attachment = array(
                                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                                'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename_path)),
                                'post_content' => '',
                                'post_status' => 'inherit'
                                );
            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename_path);
            // you must first include the image.php file
            // for the function wp_generate_attachment_metadata() to work
            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename_path );
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it should be noted that your form does not appear to have the required `MAX_FILE_SIZE` value. Please refer to the [POST method uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) section of the PHP manual.

Next, there is no such function as `insert_attachment()`, the function is [`wp_insert_attachment()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment). It requires:

- an `$attachment` array with the file attributes, etc.
- the `$filename` of the uploaded file (MUST be in the WordPress `uploads` directory ([`wp_upload_dir()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir)), so you have to take care of transferring it over, with [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) for example)
- and the `$parent_post_id`, which is presumably your current post ID, which you can get by using the [`get_the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) template function.

The [Codex page for wp_insert_attachment()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) has a great example of how to attach files (specifically images) to a post.